# How to merge two datasets according to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, merge

I want to merge two dataset like this:
The merge based on the combination of `date1`, `date2` and `date3` in `dataset2`:

```
dataset1
universeID ID     date1       date2         date3        value_1
AAA       111    01/01/2015  01/01/2016    01/03/2015   5
AAA       111    01/02/2015  01/01/2016    31/03/2015   2
AAA       112    01/01/2015  01/01/2016    01/03/2015    3
AAA       112    01/02/2015  01/01/2016    31/03/2015  0.1

dataset2
universeID  date1       date2         date3      value_2
AAA       01/01/2015  01/01/2016    01/03/2015   8
AAA       01/02/2015  01/01/2016    31/03/2015   0.2
```

Expected output:

```
universeID  ID     date1       date2         date3        value_1  value_2
AAA         111    01/01/2015  01/01/2016    01/03/2015   5        8
AAA         111    01/02/2015  01/01/2016    31/03/2015   2        0.2
AAA         112    01/01/2015  01/01/2016    01/03/2015    3       8
AAA         112    01/02/2015  01/01/2016    31/03/2015  0.1       0.2
```

So for the merged dataset, total number of rows should equals to the row number of dataset1, I tried:

```
dataset1.merge(dataset2, on=['universeID','date1', 'date2', 'date3']
```

but the row number of the final dataset > the row number of `dataset1`, the `dataset1` & `dataset2` here are just an example, can someone give me some hint what is wrong with the code and why I get more rows? I'm new to Python, this has already taken me ages.....Many thanks!

Comment: you get more rows because you're doing a cartesian product, you have duplicate keys in your dataframe.

Comment: Hi @Datanovice Could you be more specific? You mean in dataset1 I have duplicate keys and  how can I solve this issue? I'm not doing any calculation, just append ```value_2``` to dataset1 for a given combination of three dates.

Comment: @Cecilia this happens when your dataset1 or dataset2 are having duplicate keys. So you need to treat that first by taking the unique of these two frames or for each duplicate you need to select the row with the desired value1 or value2.

Comment: When I use the date for another year (same structure), I don't have this issue, I still don't understand... How can I fix this because at the moment there's no more column in dataset 2 that can match dateset1

Comment: I found the issue, yes there are duplicated keys in both datasets, I guess I'll just remove the duplicated combination and it will be fixed.

Comment: you could also use boolean filtering with `np.where` for e.g `np.where(df['ID'] == 'AAA' & df['Date1'] == '...', 0.2`